# Is there any way in T-SQL to use a dynamic operand when the operand is variable

Tags: sql-server-2016

I am trying to allow users to select the operand in a custom alert application. However, since many different versions of the alert can be setup and they will all run at the same time, I cannot create a variable to hold the operand and still run this as a set based operation (at least not that I can figure out, hence this post).

Thru a series of manipulations, I end up with a data set like this:

```
  BusinessISN | InvoiceID | InvoiceTotal | Measure | ThresholdValue 
 -------------|-----------|--------------|---------|---------------- 
    100002550 |   1165803 |       1171.8 | =       |        1616.96 
    100002315 |   1165804 |         3190 | >=      |           3000 
    100002550 |   1165806 |       473.68 | =       |        1616.96 
    100003156 |   1165807 |         1612 | <=      |           2000 
    100002550 |   1165809 |      1616.96 | =       |        1616.96 
    100002550 |   1165810 |       1760.8 | =       |        1616.96 
              |           |              |         |
```

What I would like to do is be able to compare Invoicetotal to ThresholdValue using the operand called out in Measure.

I apologize ahead of time that I cannot figure out how I am supposed to format data. I tried creating an HTML table, but even that does not seem to have worked.

Comment: See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what your desired result are, but this can be done using some dynamic SQL.

I'm assuming you want to get the `BusinessISN` and `InvoiceID` of the records where the condition expressed in the three other columns (`InvoiceTotal`, `Measure` and `ThresholdValue` ) evaluates to true - so this is what I wrote.

First, create and populate sample table (**Please** save us this step in your future questions):

```
DECLARE @T AS TABLE
(
    BusinessISN int,
    InvoiceID int,
    InvoiceTotal float,
    Measure varchar(2), 
    ThresholdValue float
)

INSERT INTO @T (BusinessISN, InvoiceID, InvoiceTotal, Measure, ThresholdValue) VALUES
(100002550, 1165803,  1171.8, '= ', 1616.96), 
(100002315, 1165804,    3190, '>=',    3000), 
(100002550, 1165806,  473.68, '= ', 1616.96), 
(100003156, 1165807,    1612, '<=',    2000), 
(100002550, 1165809, 1616.96, '= ', 1616.96), 
(100002550, 1165810,  1760.8, '= ', 1616.96);
```

Then, use a `for xml` with `stuff` to dynamically generate a `union all` query:

```
DECLARE @Sql nvarchar(max);

SELECT @Sql = STUFF
(
    (
    SELECT N' UNION ALL SELECT '+ CAST(BusinessISN as nvarchar(11)) + N' AS BusinessISN, '+ 
                       CAST(InvoiceID as nvarchar(11)) + N' AS InvoiceID '+
           N'WHERE '+ CAST(InvoiceTotal as varchar(100)) +' '+ Measure +' '+ CAST(ThresholdValue as varchar(100)) 
    FROM @T
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
, 1, 10, '')
```

Next, manually check the SQL you've created using `print`. The `print` command is your best friend when dealing with dynamic SQL.

```
PRINT @Sql
```

The print should give you the following output, though a little less organized (based on the sample data):

```
SELECT 100002550 AS BusinessISN, 1165803 AS InvoiceID WHERE 1171.8 =  1616.96 UNION ALL 
SELECT 100002315 AS BusinessISN, 1165804 AS InvoiceID WHERE 3190 >= 3000 UNION ALL 
SELECT 100002550 AS BusinessISN, 1165806 AS InvoiceID WHERE 473.68 =  1616.96 UNION ALL 
SELECT 100003156 AS BusinessISN, 1165807 AS InvoiceID WHERE 1612 <= 2000 UNION ALL 
SELECT 100002550 AS BusinessISN, 1165809 AS InvoiceID WHERE 1616.96 =  1616.96 UNION ALL 
SELECT 100002550 AS BusinessISN, 1165810 AS InvoiceID WHERE 1760.8 =  1616.96
```

Then, when you are sure you've got the correct query, all you have to do is execute it:

```
EXEC(@Sql)
```

Which should give you the following results:

```
BusinessISN     InvoiceID
100002315       1165804
100003156       1165807
100002550       1165809
```

[You can see a live demo on rextester.](https://rextester.com/IZYNR29859)

Comment: Thank you for this answer, I will see if that will work with my full solution. Sorry I didn't think about posting the table structure.